# No string to translate for "Winning bounty for question"

Tags: bug, bounties, localization, russian-stackoverflow, timeline

I can't find the string "Winning bounty for question" to translate. This string is appeared in the [timeline page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/536547/timeline) of the answer that got a bounty sometime.

> [image: winning bounty]

Comment: Ha, and I wondered what kind of strange history event "undefined reference to vtable... " was...